# Find the value of :$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{\ln x}{x^n} \rightarrow -\infty$?

Tags: limits

How to figure out that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{\ln x}{x^n} \rightarrow -\infty$ and not $\infty$, because according to L'Hopitals:

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{\ln x}{x^n} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{1/x}{nx^{n-1}}=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{1}{nx^{n}} \rightarrow \infty$$

Comment: You can't *directly* use LHopital since top initially goes to $-\infty$ while bottom goes to $0^+$ (assuming $n>0.$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: you do not have to use L'Hospital's rule when it is not necessary. Second, you should not when the hypotheses do not apply. You can see a discussion on a related case at [Why does L'Hopital's rule fail in this case?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1710786/why-does-lhopitals-rule-fail-in-this-case/1711246#1711246).

At $0^+$, $\frac{1}{x^n}\to +\infty$ (for $n>0$) and $\log x \to -\infty$, and the form $+\infty \times -\infty$ is not undeterminate, it yields here $-\infty$.

[Why does L'Hopital's rule fail in this case?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1710786/why-does-lhopitals-rule-fail-in-this-case/1711246#1711246)

Comment: How do I know when it is appropriate to use it? :)

Comment: When the form is underterminate: $0/0$ or $\pm \infty/\pm \infty$. It is a temping one, but unnecessary in many cases

Comment: I think you answered for inappropriate there haha. Ok, thanks

Comment: I do not understand. It is unappropriate to use it when the form is determinate, and it might be appropriate  when it is underterminate ($0/0$ for instance)