# Limit question - L'Hopital's rule doesn't seem to work

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, trigonometry, limits-without-lhopital

I have been recently trying to solve this limit problem. First of all, I used L'Hopital's rule but it doesn't seem to work (because I thought that this limit is of form $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$). Am I doing it correctly? I don't seem to understand where am I wrong.

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(\frac{x+\sin^3x}{5x+6}\right)$$

Comment: Try to factor out $x$

Comment: It's probably easier to just use squeeze theorem

Comment: To your question why L'Hopital failed: You have to read the statement very carefully! The theorem states, if $\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)=\lim_{x\to x_0} g(x)\in\{0,\infty\}$ **and** $\lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ exists, **then** there holds $\lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$. It is not said, that this limits are equivalent, but only if the RHS exists, it is the same as the LHS. Your example is a nice counterexample, where the RHS don't exists, while the LHS do.

Comment: @AkshayYadav, please consider accepting an answer which solved your problem, there are already many good answers out there, just go and accept one... Cheers :-)

Comment: @VidyanshuMishra I don't get what you mean by 'accepting an answer which solved my problem', can you elaborate?

Comment: There is  a check mark on the left hand of each answer,  if you click on that it means you have accepted that answer. You accept an answer which you like the most.click

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1710786/why-does-lhopitals-rule-fail-in-this-case

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does L'Hopital's rule fail in calculating $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x}{x+\sin(x)}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1710786/why-does-lhopitals-rule-fail-in-calculating-lim-x-to-infty-fracxx-s)

Answer (score 43):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x+\sin^3x}{5x+6}=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1+\frac{\sin^3x}{x}}{5+\frac{6}{x}}=\frac{1}{5}$$

Comment: Sir, how did you concluded that $\lim_{x \to \infty} (\sin^3(x)/x)=0$. Moreover can you tell me why did L'Hospital rule failed?

Comment: @Akshay Yadav Because  $-1\leq\sin^3x\leq1$, which gives $-\frac{1}{|x|}\leq\frac{\sin^3x}{x}\leq\frac{1}{|x|}$. The  L'Hospital rule failed because $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}(\sin^3x)'$ does not exist.

Answer (score 29):

L'Hospital's Rule isn't working since the derivative of numerator function **isn't** determinable when $x \to \infty$, due to oscillatory behaviour of $\sin$ and $\cos$ function. Therefore you have to approach traditionally.

Answer (score 17):

We can squeeze $(x+\sin^3x)/(5x+6)$ between two applications of l'Hopital: When $5x+6>0$ we have        $$\frac {x-1}{5x+6}\leq \frac {x+\sin^3x}{5x+6}\leq \frac {x+1}{5x+6}.$$ Applying l'Hopital to the far left and far right of the above line, we see they both have limits of $1/5$ as $x\to \infty.$ So the expression in the middle must also go to $1/5$.

Of course we could also re-write the far L & far R as $\frac {1}{5}(1- \frac {11}{5x+6})$ and $\frac {1}{5}(1-\frac {1}{5x+6})$ and not need l'Hopital.

Answer (score 10):

One of the conditions of applying L'Hospital's Rule is that $f'(x)/g'(x)$ must exist.
$$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$$

After one application of L'Hospitals, you arrived at a finite numerator over a finite denominator.  But while the numerator was finite, it was non-convergent, and so that limit did not exist.  Just like the much simpler $\sin(x)$ does not converge to a single value when x approaches infinity -- it oscillates between +/-1. $$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} {\sin(x)}$$

So all of L'Hospital's pre-conditions must exist for you to use it.  As others have mentioned, this limit could more easily be solved by using the squeezing theorem.  The numerator's value gets squeezed between $x+1$ and $x-1$. Both of those limits go to $1/5$.

Answer (score 3):

For some limits  L'Hospital rule doesn't seem to work ,like what you write $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(\frac{x+\sin^3(x)}{5x+6}\right)\\\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(\frac{3x+\cos(x)}{x+6\sin(2x)}\right)\\\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}} \left(\frac{\tan x}{\tan (3x)}\right)\\\lim_{x \to 0} \left(\frac{\cot (2x)}{x^2+\cot x}\right)\\\vdots$$ but (all i see ) have alternative solution ,or change something you may use L'Hospital rule .
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(\frac{x+\sin^3(x)}{5x+6}\right)=\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(\frac{x(1+\frac{\sin^3(x)}{x})}{x(5+\frac6x)}\right)=\\\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(\frac{(1+\frac{\sin^3(x)}{x})}{(5+\frac6x)}\right)=\frac15$$ for $\\\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}} \left(\frac{\tan x}{\tan (3x)}\right)$ we have 
$$\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}} \left(\frac{\tan x}{\tan (3x)}\right)=\\\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}} \left(\frac{\frac{1}{\cot x}}{\frac{1}{\cot 3x}}\right)=\\\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}} \left(\frac{\cot 3x}{\cot x}\right)$$ now you can use L'Hospital rule

I think when you have a trig function $\to \infty $ L'Hospital rule is not suitable