# Converse of L'Hospital

Tags: limits

L'Hospital's Rule:  If ${f(x)}\over{g(x)}$ is either $0\over0$ or $\infty\over\infty$, then the $\lim_{x\to \infty}$${f(x)}\over{g(x)}$ $=$ $\lim_{x\to \infty}$${f'(x)}\over {g'(x)}$.  What I want to know is if the converse is true.

In other words, if $\lim_{x\to \infty}$${f(x)}\over{g(x)}$ $=$ $\lim_{x\to \infty}$${f'(x)}\over {g'(x)}$, then is ${f(x)}\over{g(x)}$equal to one of  $0\over0$ or $\infty\over\infty$?  By this I mean that there does not exist a case in which L'Hopital does not apply yet gives the correct answer.
It is not a repeat of another question, as many have suggested.  I would ask those people to take a look at the question that they have said I have repeated.  These are two different questions, and it surprises me that they could have been confused.

Comment: 1) You are missing hypothesis in L'Hopital. 2) No.

Comment: there are 7 indeterminate forms out of which L.H rule can be applied to only two ?(guess what)

Comment: This [10 January 2006 sci.math post](http://mathforum.org/kb/thread.jspa?messageID=4183116) is relevant.

Comment: I think this post is really worth reading and pretty much sums it all up. Answer by B. Cipra: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1710786/why-does-lhopitals-rule-fail-in-this-case/1710798#1710798

Comment: Read the final sentence of this question. It's not a duplicate. The OP isn't asking about situations where L'Hopital might seem to apply but doesn't; he's asking if there can be situations where L'Hopital manifestly does not apply but happens to give the right answer anyway.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro hello Dave, I know it's very old post... But can you address me again to the post you mention in your comment. (The link seem not to point to it.) Thanks!

Comment: @dfnu: Searching in google's archive of the Usenet group "sci.math" -- I selected the top hit for the google search [sci.math + google](https://www.google.com/search?q=sci.math+google), then searched within there for [Renfro + L'Hopital](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/search?q=Renfro%20L%27Hopital), then looked for the closest matching date -- led me to what is almost certainly the [10 January 2006 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/uAHG9On6d_A/m/j60pitxP5GIJ) I previously cited. The post is overkill for the OP's question and it was **(continued)**

Comment: only intended to give a reference for more nuanced and advanced issues related to the OP's question, for those who might be interested. About a year ago I posted some more references in mathoverflow that I've known about since the early 1990s but don't believe I've ever posted in an online math group before -- see my comments to [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/414138/15780).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro yes I had reached it already and found it very interesting. I'm reading right now Young's paper! Do you know of any work on when the converse of de l'Hospital Theorem holds? Thanks again!

Comment: @dfnu: Unless I'm misunderstanding what you mean by the/a converse of L'Hopital's theorem, the most natural converse is an immediate consequence of the generalized *liminf*-*limsup* version $\liminf \frac{f'}{g'}\leq\liminf\frac{f}{g}\leq\limsup\frac{f}{g}\leq\limsup\frac{f'}{g'},$ since if $\frac{f'}{g'}$ exists (finitely or infinitely), then we have $\liminf \frac{f'}{g'}=\limsup\frac{f'}{g'},$ from which it follows that $\liminf\frac{f}{g}=\limsup\frac{f}{g},$ and hence $\lim \frac{f}{g}$ exists (respectively, finitely or infinitely).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Sorry I did not formulate my question properly. What I mean is: are there any conditions on $f$ and $g$ under which we can state that *if the limit $f'/g'$ does not exist, then neither does the limit of $f/g$*?

Comment: @dfnu: I don't know of any off-hand. I'll try to look further when I have the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x^2} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{0}{2x} = 0$$
even though the initial limit did not have an indeterminate form. That is, it is *possible* that you could get the right answer by applying L'Hopital even in cases where it is invalid. You could think of this as the calculus equivalent of the fake proof that
$$
\frac{16}{64}=\frac{1}{4}
$$
where you cancel out the sixes.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=x+\sin(x), g(x)=x$.

Then 
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} =2$$
by the squeeze theorem but 
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} =\lim_{x \to \infty} 1+\cos(x) = DNE$$