# Failure of L'Hopital's Rule

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, proof-writing, solution-verification

> Give an example of continuously differentiable functions $f$,$g:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ for which $f(x_0)=g(x_0)=0$ and $\nabla f(x_0) = \lambda \nabla g(x_0) \neq 0$, for some point $x_0$ and number $\lambda$, but
>       $$\lim\limits_{x\to x_0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$$
>       does not exist.

### Proof

Let the $i$th component of $g(x)$ be given by $g(x_i) = \frac{1}{x_{0_i}}(x_i^2-x_{0_i}^2)$.

Let the $i$th component of $f(x)$ be given by $f(x_i) = x_i-x_{0_i}$.

Then $f(x_0) = g(x_0) = 0$ and $\nabla g(x_0) = 2$, and $\nabla f(x_0) = 1$.

However, this limit is identical to $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{x}$, which is known to not exist.

> Something about this proof seems invalid to me.

Comment: Only thing I see wrong is that it is the components of the gradients that are $2$ and $1$ respectively. That and the fact that you need to assume that all components of $x_0$ are nonzero for this example, but that's OK because it just needs to be a particular example of failure.

Comment: @Ian, What does the OP mean by "the $i$th component of $g(x)$"? There is an $i$th component of $x\in\mathbb{R^n}$, but $g(x)$ is a single real number. Same for $f(x)$.

Comment: What is your version of L'Hospital's rule in $\mathbb{R}^n$? I've seen generalizations to $\mathbb{R}^2$ only but even that is not a very popular theorem.

Comment: @BarryCipra Maybe they mean to say $g(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{x_i^2-(x_0)_i}{(x_0)_i}$ and $f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i - (x_0)_i$?