# $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x}{x+\sin(x)}$

Tags: limits

The limit from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1710786/945054) doesn't exist. But in Desmos, tye function surely approaches $1$ as $x$ gets larger and larger. Why does the limit not exist and how to check such one?

Comment: The limit does exist and is $1$, which is exactly what the linked question states.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question you linked to.  The author of that post was asking why a particular method for computing that limit failed to yield the correct answer (which is clearly $1$).  The users who posted solutions clearly and simply explained why that particular method doesn't work in this case.

Comment: L'Hopital's rule doesn't actually fail. Just one particular method fails.

Comment: If $f'(x)/g'(x)$ has a limit, etc., then $f(x)/g(x)$ has the same limit.  But $f'(x)/g'(x)$ doesn't have a limit, so l'Hopital doesn't say anything about $f(x)/g(x)$

Answer (score 3):

Just note that for large enough $x$ we have the inequality
$$
\dfrac{x}{x+1} \leq \dfrac{x}{x+\sin x} \leq \dfrac{x}{x-1}
$$

Since the upper an the lower bounds tend to 1 as $x \to +\infty$, the same happens to the function we are studying. L'Hôpital's rule only provides the answer if the new limit exists, which is not the case here.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\dfrac{x}{x + \sin(x)} = \lim_{x\to \infty}\dfrac{1}{1 + \frac{\sin(x)}{x}}= \dfrac{1}{1 + 0}= 1$$

Note that, $$\boxed{\lim_{x\to \infty} \dfrac{\sin x}{x}= 0}$$